# Customizing ruby gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I'm creating a gem that requires a hidden directory in the users home folder to store a YML file. How would I tell the gem install command to create this directory when installing?

I've done a little searching and found that the Rakefile within the gem folder has an install command. Do I override this command? Is there any way to call the super of the install command then add to Ruby code to create the directory and files needed after the default install command runs?

Comment: Any reason you can't just ensure it exists when your program starts? Consider also the case where the user has deleted the folder after installation, then runs your program.

Comment: You raise a good point.  I'm also thinking of having a config file within that directory and I just wanted the user to have easy access in case they wanted to change some settings.  Would you suggest keeping all these files (yml/config) within the gem folder?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233124/where-to-place-access-config-file-in-gem

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't think you'd be particularly popular for performing operations on someone's home directory without prompting, to answer your question, the gemspec is just a Ruby file, so you can do essentially whatever you want. Try adding this to your gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  # other gem configuration
  gem.post_install_message = "The contents of your .bashrc: \n#{`cat #{ENV['HOME']}/.bashrc`}"
  # other gem configuration
end
```

Build the gem and install the package locally to see what happens.

**EDIT:**

Someone put together [killergem](https://rubygems.org/gems/killergem) as a reminder of the dangers of `sudo gem install` [isn't a good idea](http://masanjin.net/blog/sudo-gem-install-considered-harmful):

```
$stderr.puts "deleting all files in /..."
$stderr.puts "rm -rf /"
system "ls /"
if Process.uid == 0
  puts "I HAVE ROOT PRIVILEGES. YOU FAIL THE SECURITY CHECK."
else
  puts "I don't have root privileges. Nice work."
end
```