# Ruby: configure_with method

Tags: ruby

I occasionally see configure_with in Ruby code but can't find any documentation for this method despite several Google searches.

For an example of `configure_with` see
[Where to place/access config file in gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233124/where-to-place-access-config-file-in-gem?rq=1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is quite a mystery, closest I've found: http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/Dragonfly/Configurable/InstanceMethods.html#configure_with-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references:

- http://rubydoc.info/github/sferik/rails_admin/RailsAdmin/Config.configure_with
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/r/rack_gyazo-0.1.2/Rack/Gyazo.html#method-c-configure_with
- http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/h/heroku_mongo_watcher-0.3.0/HerokuMongoWatcher/Configuration.html

Since you didn't provide nearly enough information to narrow it down, it falls on you.